# file.java has weird writing after using terminal to make jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar, terminal

I used the Mac terminal to make a JAR file and after I wrote `jar cvf` I forgot to wrote the name of the JAR file and wrote the Java files I wanted like this:

`jar cvf Book.java Library.java Patron.java README`

instead of:

`jar cvf ex0.jar Book.java Library.java Patron.java README`

and now my `Book.java` file is all messy and no words in it

it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SXy5.png) now.

Does anyone know how can I get it back like it previously was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gone. You just created a jar file called `Book.java` containing the other files and overwriting the original `Book.java`. The file isn't "messy", it's a jar/zip file and of course there aren't any words in it because it's compressed binary.

Now it's time to get the file back from version control. If you're not using version control, it's time to rewrite `Book.java` and learn how to use version control.

Comment: phew just remebered that I have history for files in intelij ID